# How to compare old password from migrated data using bcrypt?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, hash, sha1, bcrypt

I recently migrated my users table from SQL Server to Mongodb using Pentaho ETL tool. The password field is binary data type but I am using bycrypt to hash password in Nodejs for all new user creation, so how do I compare my old users password with bcrypt since that is encrypted using SQL Server?

Here is a sample SQL Server password:

> 0x010000008F0985DA84A7F12633E8EF1AA121A0AE6FB0F4049F9BDDAF326045AA8F5F6AF7

Comment: Big trouble. A hash is a [one-way function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function), so by definition it is _very_ hard to get the clear text value out of the hash, which you would need to pass it to bcrypt, then take the user input and compare it. If you use [SQL Server 2012, you are in real trouble](http://sqlity.net/en/2460/sql-password-hash/), since a 32bit salt is applied as well. A password migration is a pretty hard thing to do. How to approach it really depends on your use case and stuff.

Comment: There's a lot of "you can't" floating around here, but this seems to be to be wrong. It is correct to say that you can't unhash the password, but surely you can just decode the hash/salt components and then build that hashing and salting into your Mongo system?

Comment: To make a practical start on this, how about you find a low-value account in your SQL Server database and show us what the hash field looks like, edited into your question?

Comment: (I have downvoted as the post required significant case repair to be readable. Please make a solid effort when writing your questions here, thanks.)

Comment: @halfer updated the Qusetion with a sample SQL Server password.

Comment: @halfer I am actually thinking of this. Something like using the `$id$` notation used in `/etc/shadow` to denote the type of hash used (is there one for bcrypt, yet?). Then compare the user input and known salt against the algorithm denoted. After the user is authenticated, the user input could be saved as a bcrypted value.

Comment: @Markus: I don't know about the shadow file - I think that is just for *nix system users, though you may be right that the same principle applies. The link you supplied at the start shows how to retrieve the hash for `0x0100` passwords, so I think this is very achievable. The question really is "how to replicate the hashing and salting algorithm in SQL Server 2012?".

Comment: @halfer: So, we have a SHA1 password from a version prior to 2012. This can be easily dismantled. Next 4 characters are salt, the remaining part is a SHA1 hash consisting of the salt and the users password.

Comment: OK, yes @Markus. If that is the case, then that's an answer that can be posted below. Perhaps a good approach would be to model this in SQL Server first, before trying to recreate it in Node. (I suggest that doing it in Node is out of scope anyway - the OP should be left with _some_ work to do!)

Comment: @halfer Since I neither have the possibility of running an SQL Server nor have any clue about it, I'd appreciate if you would take the choir. Free beer when you are around Cologne, Germany in exchange?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg instead if i come in chat would that help ?

Comment: @Melvin We can try... Please open one.

Comment: @Markus: I am the same, I have no SQL Server, nor the time to dig into a potentially time-consuming problem. We have added a good number of leads for the OP already, so they have plenty of research to be getting on with. I will add a small answer though to summarise what can be done.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg join here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162090/smartgeeks

Answer (score 2):

In general, password hashing algorithms will contain a salt, and as Markus has pointed out, SQL Server uses the SHA series of hashing algorithms. The [useful link supplied](http://sqlity.net/en/2460/sql-password-hash/) earlier shows that hashes beginning with `0x0100` are hashed using SHA1.

Furthermore, SQL Server seems to use a salting system, quite rightly. The point of this is to ensure that even if a rainbow table were available for a specific hashing algorithm, adding this extra random obfuscation means that you would need custom rainbow tables per row, which is the same as needing to brute-force each row without pre-computation help.

Salts tend to be merged into hash values, but they are not themselves secret, so they can be trivially extracted. So, all is not lost - this is what you need to do:

### Implement the old algorithm in Mongo first

- Use the above link to determine what part of this field is hash and what part is salt.
- Using SQL Server to start with, you should be able to recreate your hash value based on this algorithm:

  ```
  hash = algorithm(password + salt)
  ```

  Of course, you will need a row where you know the password, but you can just create a dummy row for this purpose.
- Then, once you have worked this out, copy the hash and salt values per row to your Mongo database
- Recreate your SQL Server code in Mongo and/or Node
- Add a new value in each of your Mongo user documents to represent the algorithm you are using (probably `sha1`)

### Transfer users to the new algorithm when you next see their password

- When users log into your new system, they will supply their password and you can look up what test to do based on the algorithm column.
- If they log in successfully and they have an old algorithm, recreate the hash based on Bcrypt and then change the algorithm value to `bcrypt`.

I will leave the specific task of extracting the hash and the salt as an exercise for the reader. It looks like it is pretty much spelled out in the link supplied anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to decrypt the passwords you got from SQL Server `sys.syslogins` table? If so, the answer is simple: **You can't**. Those passwords are hashed, and I'm pretty sure that they're salted as well (probably with a different salt for algorithm for each version of SQL Server for added security). You can't just decrypt them; they're designed so that they can't be.

Comment: That is simply wrong. They are NOT encrypted, but hashed. Very big difference.

Comment: I'll change the word to hashed for you... The answer, however, remains unchanged; **you can't**.

Comment: Well, with an encryption there probably would be a way without using brute force. With a 32bit salted SHA-512, it is out of scope whatsoever ;)

Comment: @Larnu No i just have a column named userpassword in user table which is encrypted using pwdencrypt now in nodejs i use bycrypt to hash a password so how will i compare my old users password using bycrypt.I ask this because hashing is one way and encryption at any time can be decrypted.In simple words how will i compare my encrypted password using bycrypt which uses hash.

Comment: @Melvin PWDENCRYPT is misusing terminology (which proves again that terminology matters). Actually, they are hashed.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg so since pwdencrypt are hashed i can just compare it with bycrypt ?

Comment: @Melvin Hash algorithms are incompatible with each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do what you want. You can’t just change the hashing algorithm for an existing website; you have to continue to support the old algorithm until all users have logged in at least once since you introduced the new algorithm, giving you a chance to re-hash their password (this will generally be never, unless you eventually decide to just deactivate the accounts for users who haven’t logged in for a long time).

What you need to do is to re-implement the SQL Server password hashing algorithm so that you can continue to use it to verify passwords for your existing users, and then re-hash their passwords using bcrypt and save the new hash. This may be impossibly difficult for you, in which case your options are to migrate back to SQL Server or to do a mandatory password reset for all your users.